# django avatar showing old image when size mentioned in template tag

Tags: django

After changing the avatar, if I use

```
{% avatar user %}
```

it is showing newly added correct image.

But if I show avatar using:

```
{% avatar user size %}
```

it is showing old image.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

django-avatar has really weird behavior or avatar's url cache when you use custom avatar sizes. Basically, invalidate_cache() function deletes caches only for known sizes, listed in settings.AVATAR_AUTO_GENERATE_SIZES. If you don't have your size there, the cache will never invalidate.

So, if you have

```
{% avatar user 256 %}
```

in your template, just add

```
AVATAR_AUTO_GENERATE_SIZES = [256]
```

to your django project settings.

Or, as a workaround, just disable the cache:

```
AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED = False
```

PS: It's actual for latest 3.0.0 version.